# Active record filtering in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, database-design

I have a legacy database where 70% of all tables have 'valid_from' and 'valid_to' columns.
These columns indicate that a record is 'active' and can be used at production time.
We also have these columns on association tables which are used for many-to-many relations.

Because only active records should be used we have to filter the active ones whenever a read query is invoked.
We're planning to do this with a global filter that is always set in the Hibernate Session by an AOP Advice. By this, the invoker never has to worry about setting the Hibernate filter.

We're worrying about the following:
1) We didn't create a separate class for association tables so we're worrying how to filter active records from such tables. Is it possible just to mention the 'valid_from' and 'valid_to' fields in the filter that maps to an association table while these fields are not explicitly known by Hibernate? Will this work?

2) The filter should not be used for tables which don't have the valid fields. But filter is always set. Will this give any issues?

3) The valid fields are managed by a web based 'admin-tool'. How can we change the valid fields on association tables without explicitly creating a 'mapping class'? We really want to avoid such classes! Or perhaps there's a better approach to handle the active records in general?

All help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to throw some comments here. Hopefully, it can help you somehow.

---

1. AssociationOverride is the only way I know to achieve this (it does require extra classes). Take a look at: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/
2. I do not see any issue.
3. If you figure out a way to create your mappings without AssociationOverride; then, you probably need to build a regular JDBC utility to update these fields.

---

Alternatively, you can handle this scenario differently. Every Entity would have a @Formula property called "isActive" based on "valid_from"-"valid_to" columns. Next, you could filter the results properly using HQL or Criteria.

I hope it helps.

Comment: For item 2: won't this give any issues like 'invalid column'?

Comment: @user2054927 I see what you mean now. Yes, it might be an issue. Of course, there are ugly and error prone workarounds for this that I would not advice.